# Xcode - SenTestingKit not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have an issue that popped up when I upgraded my version of xcode.  I  use unit tests, and I now when I try to import SenTestingKit (`#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>`), I get this error: `SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h: No such file or directory`.

I have looked at my build settings, and I have the following configuration options:

```
== Linking ==
Other Linker Flags: -framework Foundation -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit
Prebinding: No

== Search Paths ==
Debug Configutation: "/iphonesimulator4.0/Developer/Library/Frameworks" "/Xcode4/Library/Frameworks"
```

I've checked `/Xcode4/Library/Frameworks`, and the `SenTestingKit.framework/` directory *is* there.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Sam, all Apple software in pre-release is under an SDK, so you won't (read: probably shouldn't) be able to discuss it outside of the Apple Developer forums. Post there, file a bug.

Comment: Typeoneerror, you mean an NDA. It is an SDK.

Comment: Questions like this are better asked on the Apple Developer Forums, where you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I understand all that, but this could be answered about xcode generally.  Search Paths and linker settings are present in xcode 3 as well.  So I've edited the question to take the references to Xcode 4 out to make it a "general xcode" question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - except with Frameworks that I have built. No matter what the search path is, it cannot find them. Time to file a bug!

Comment: "Abizern" setting a new record: the most hilarious thing ever typed.  More likely to get an answer on Apple forums?  Seriously?

Answer (score 57):

I had this same issue when creating a new test case in XCode. However, this was due to stupidity of me selecting the wrong target when creating the test case.

Using "File New...", the test case was being included and compiled with the target application settings instead of test case's target. Checking the Build Phases tab and looking in the "Compile Sources" disclosure revealed my particular issue.

Comment: Yep this worked. I did this previously but I think AppCode reset it back. If you are using AppCode double check.

Answer (score 18):

I had this issue after upgrading to xcode 4.3.  Nothing seemed to work until I came across [this post](http://forum.sparrow-framework.org/topic/cant-run-unit-tests).  I already had the same search paths, but changing the order solved the issue.

So from the article, you need the two following values in your Framework Search Paths, **in this order**.

```
$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

Comment: That is because (SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks is arm, $(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks is intel

Comment: @velexa - So your point is that the second one is unnecessary or...?  Anyway, just relaying the information that I had this issue and the solution on that board seemed to wok.

Comment: i am just explaining why your solution works, yes adding paths to intel framework builds to a arm target is unnecessary

Comment: @velexa - Maybe I'm missing something, but the iphone simulator is not an arm target.  That's what we're building against.

Comment: the target of the project you run in the simulator says arm under it's architecture settings, it will not use frameworks from $(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks but /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/ when ran in the simulator, you could add that path to the end of your list just as well with no effect , the arm frameworks for your arm target are in $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks , that is the only path you need in the list

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I had to move `$(inherited)` to the bottom of the list too.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue because there's a space in my Xcode installation: `/Xcode 4.0.2`

I fixed it by adding `"${DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR}/Frameworks"` (with the quotes) to my Framework Search Paths.

Comment: In my case I also had to add quotes around `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: Or just use `$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

For my Framework Search Paths, I've explicitly added `/$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks`.  Compiles correctly for simulator and device.

I am sure there are  environment variables so that it works across SDK versions, so I will update answer if I find them.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This solved the problem for me. That is, I added the framework from that path, and Xcode 4 automatically updated the Framework SearchPaths after that. I initially tried to use the SenTestingKit.framework in $(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Library/Frameworks/, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To clear this up once for all, there are three SenTestingKit frameworks in Xcode SDK, one is for OS X, one is for iOS and one is for the simulator.

Had you ran "lipo -info" on them you would have seen that

Architectures in the fat file: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/Versions/A/SenTestingKit are: x86_64 i386

Architectures in the fat file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit is architecture: armv7

Non-fat file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit is architecture: i386

Comment: Still doesn't clear it up. When you select add framework in xcode it only gives you the option to "SenTestingKit" it doesn't let you select a specific non osx one.

Comment: Thats bad Xcode for you, i always just manually drag the framework folder from Finder into Xcode and party like its the 90's

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check that Xcode is checking the Framework Search Paths: [image: Framework Search Paths]

Comment: Yes. I added ${DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR}/Frameworks to the Framework Search Paths and that fixed it.