# XCode 4.5 giving me "SenTestingKit/SenTestKit.h" file not found, but works on 4.4.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5

I just installed XCode 4.5 and it's giving me a 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h" file not found error on one of my existing projects.  This error only happens in XCode 4.5, but it compiles fine on 4.4.1.  I've checked that the SenTesting framework has been added to the test target and I verified that the same error occurs on a few other machines.  Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

*UPDATE* 
I was able to fix this issue by placing quotes around some of the framework search paths in build settings...

"$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

"$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks"

Since I installed the XCode 4.5 GM alongside 4.4.1, I'm guessing the 4.5 version had a space somewhere in the name.

Comment: I'm using SenTestingKit in conjuction with CocoaPods. In this case, you'll also want to add:

`${inherited}`

first in the Framework Search Paths setting in your test target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it's just missing the framework and before it just referenced it and not copied to your project folder.

This might help:
You can click on your App Name and then the "Build Phases" tab near center of screen.  Then go down to "Link Binary with Libraries" and click the "+" symbol and type "SenTest" and the framework should appear.  Double-click it and it will add it to your project.  In your project explorer you may want to "drag" that into the "Frameworks" folder just for organization.

I don't have same error and have both versions of XCode so am just guessing what it could be.  I hope this is helpful.

---

Also that is pre-release software so might not be able to discuss publicly.  See this SO article regarding similar issue during previous upgrade.

SEE:  [Xcode - SenTestingKit not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354891/xcode-sentestingkit-not-found)

Comment: I have noticed at times the order of the frameworks listed in the Build Phases tab also affects compiling so try changing the order.  I tend to keep core stuff at the top and additional below.

Comment: I was able to fix this from one of the responses in that link you sent me, see my update above.  Thank you!

Comment: Pleasure to have helped.  I know I continue to need that 2nd pair of eyes from time to time myself to happy to pay it forward.  Good luck with the update to iOS6.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with libxml in XCode 4.5 and I managed to solve it by changing the reference to the framework in Build Settings of the target. Strangely, I changed ($SDKROOT) to "($SDK_DIR)" (notice the "") and it worked. Don't know why but it fixed it.
Maybe this will help

BTW, if anyone knows why the "" fixed it, I would be glad to know !

Comment: This fixed my problem. The reason for the quotes is that the path to $SDKROOT contains spaces (in my case, /Applications/Xcode 4.5GM.app/Contents/…) and a path with spaces must be quoted.

Comment: Ok for your answer but in my case, if I quoted the whole path like "($SDKROOT)/the/path" it wouldn't work... really strange...

Answer (score 0):

`SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h` file not found error on one of my existing projects. You can click on your App Name and then the **Build Phases**.