# Compile error in building AVFoundation.framework in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, avfoundation, xcode4.5

I've upgraded XCode 4.5 today and built my project.
A compile-error shows:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAudioMix.h:15:9:
'MediaToolbox/MTAudioProcessingTap.h' file not found
```

The error occurs even I add MediaToolbox in my Project Settings-> Build Phase.

The strange truth is I create a new project and just import the AVFoundation.framework.
It works.

Here's my environment:

```
Mac OS X version: 10.7.4 
Xcode Version: 4.5 (4G182) 
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)
```

I've tried
[XCode 4.5 giving me "SenTestingKit/SenTestKit.h" file not found, but works on 4.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498868/xcode-4-5-giving-me-sentestingkit-sentestkit-h-file-not-found-but-works-on-4)
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built successfully after I filled
Targets->Build Settings->Search Paths->Framework Search Paths
 $(inherited) only or made it clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting both frameworks, then adding them both back, the MediateToolbox first.